# Let $p\geq 5$ be a prime. Show that $\sum_{k=0}^{\frac {p-1}{2}} {\binom p k}3^k \equiv 2^p-1 \pmod {p^2}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $p\geq 5$ be a prime. Show that 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\frac {p-1}{2}} {\binom p k}3^k \equiv 2^p-1 \pmod {p^2}$$

I couldn't prove that $p^2$ divides it.

---

***My solution that $\text {mod } p$ works***:

Since each term except ${\binom p 0} 3^0$ is divisible by $p$, we are left to show that $1+pk \equiv 2^p-1 \pmod p$. By *Fermat's Little Theorem*, $p\mid 2^p-2$, so the rest follows clearly.